# VS2012 RC, AjaxControlToolkit and Smart Tags not appearing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ajaxcontroltoolkit, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS2012 RC. I have used Nuget to add in the Ajax Control Toolkit.

A few questions:

1. Should the Toolbox populate with the AJAX Controls? I understand that I can add them in by creating a new tab and adding the dll, but do I need to do that everytime I start a new web project?
2. In VS2008 when I included the AJAX Control Toolkit smart tags would start appearing on things like a textbox control allowing me to add an extender. In VS2012 the Smart tags do not appear so I end up manually having to add the extender to the code. Is this as expected? or is something not configured properly?
3. I commonly use the textbox watermark control instead of labels for form fields. What is the preferred way to add watermark text? AJAXControl Toolkit or JQuery?